# Rsync files in local directories and chmod issues

Tags: command, rsync

When I do rsync this is my command:

```
rsync -a source dest
```

I am using dest as my web root `/var/www/`
so some folder which are set to `chmod 777` were no longer with `777` permission.
does `rsync` change folder permission as well?

What is best way to sync two local folders in same server.? Will `rsync` delete any changes done in destination and use the source files?

Answer (score 1):

The manual page for `rsync` says this:

```
-a, --archive    archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)
```

Among those options is `-p`, about which it says:

```
-p, --perms      preserve permissions
```

So, yes, `rsync` is making the permissions on `dest` match those on `source` in this case. If that is not desired, then read the manual page and decide what options are more appropriate to your need than `rsync -a`, and use those instead. In the simplest case, add the `--no-perms` flag *after* `-a` to disable the permission preservation.

Comment: Type `man rsync` or `rsync --help` in your terminal, or checkout rsync.samba.org

Comment: What do you suggest to use for web project where i need to keep permission of the files and folders in web root same.

Comment: I would probably have a post-transfer script that explicitly set the permissions the way they need to be, rather than relying on updates not messing them up.

Comment: can we use cp command instead of rsnc if we are doing copying in same server

Comment: You can, but `cp`, depending on how you run it, can also mess with permissions if you're not careful. Make sure you know what user it will be running as, what the user's `umask` will be at the time it is run, and what options will be passed to `cp` to understand what will/won't be preserved/modified by the transfer, and how those will affect files that are being overwritten vs. new files that are being created, as well as the expected effects on the directory structure's permissions.